# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin; Unable to tag SCM

Tags: git, maven

I'm using the `maven-release-plugin` to prepare releases for my project.

I added the plugin like this:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
    </plugin>
```

And the Git repo is set up like this:

```
  <scm>
    <url>http://my-repo.com:7990/projects/repos/my-project</url>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@my-repo.com:7999/wrap/my-project.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@my-repo.com:7999/wrap/my-project.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>my-project-1.1</tag>
  </scm>
```

However, when I am running this:

```
  mvn release:prepare
```

I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project my-project: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Permission denied (publickey).
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
```

Comment: It looks like you are not allowed to connect, if you try to add remote ssh/user@host/path/to/project.git and then push to this remote, does it work?

Comment: Shouldn't your scm url be : scm:git:http://my-repo.com:7990/projects/repos/my-project ? as per this link https://maven.apache.org/components/scm/git.html

Comment: @htulsiani and doesn't it correspond to that format?

Comment: I have tried that address as well but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried with  `<connection>scm:git:https://git@my-repo.com:7999/wrap/my-project.git</connection>`?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. It turned out to be that Maven did not have permission to publish to my Github repository on my behalf. This is required in order for it to be able to generate a new release tag. My project is a Jenkins plugin, so I [found the answer in the Jenkins developer wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Hosting+Plugins#HostingPlugins-Requestuploadpermissions):

> However if your plugin is hosted on GitHub and you have different username and/or password for GitHub and jenkins-ci.org use of the command-line arguments for username/password will result in errors. You will have to start an ssh-agent and import your private key so the release plugin can access the GitHub repository (see [Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](http://%20https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/))...

Of course the first step will be to [create a new SSH key and add it to your SSH client](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) if you don't already have one.

Here's the procedure I followed (from the instructions in the links above).

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter a file in which to save the key (/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa): [Press enter]
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a passphrase]
Enter same passphrase again: [Type passphrase again]
```

Then add the new SSH key to your SSH agent.

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 59566
```

Open `~/.ssh/config` with your favorite editor and add this:

```
Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then run:

```
$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Copy the public key into your clipboard:

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Go to Github and from the chevron next to your avatar choose **Settings>SSH and GPG keys>New SSH key**, paste the public key, value, give it a name you'll later recognize and save.

That should be it.

Then go to Github